# Communication system using PiFmRds between two pis

Tags: pifm

I would like to use PiFmRds as a communication method between two of my Pis.

I would like to be able to encode text or other data into the RDS RT (64 chars) and then decode it once received.

Or even generate some sort of sound (e.g different pitches for different letter) and then write some python script to decode it) Sort of like morse code.

Is the Raspberry Pi capable of picking up an FM signal (without use of extra hardware, other than a wire as antenna) And if so, does anyone know a good RDS Decoder for the Raspberry Pi?